# map characters before imagettftext()?

Tags: php, imagettftext

I'm building a free font website with font previews. Many of the font characters generated by imagettftext() are coming up with square boxes because they are not mapped.

I look at a site like dafont.com, and all of their fonts preview correctly. I highly doubt they are going though each font and making sure the right characters are being used.

So the question I have is, is there a PHP script or function that can do this:

1) open a ttf file and find mapped characters based on a string. EX: I want to pass the name 'foobar' to imagettftext() as the text, but if the font foobar only maps uppercase characters, I would have to pass FOOBAR to imagettftext().

2) if any character in the returned string is not mapped in the font, find the next mapped character and replace it with that.

Basically, I'm trying to avoid all unmapped font boxes from appearing on my site.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with several fonts from [dafont.com](http://datfont.com). Unmapped characters usually show up as blank (nothing) using `imagettftext`. I tried to access characters outside the bounds of a font by entering `&#752;` for example. However, even on [dafont.com](http://datfont.com), there are some fonts that have those squares in them; **for example [this Flower Ornaments font](http://www.dafont.com/flower-ornaments.font) or [this 4yeo Sport font](http://www.dafont.com/4yeo-sport.font)**.

My guess is that those basic characters are mandatory and thus are replaced with an empty box.

My personal suggestions for dingbats and text fonts are:

1. **Dingbats**: Display a static text for dingbats fonts. This is what [dafont.com](http://datfont.com) does, no matter how much you change the sample text, the font sample will remain the same and thus you will never see those boxes unless you click to see the mapping details.
2. **Text fonts:** If you are certain that the font has standard English alphabet in it, print out *"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"* for every text font. It will give the user an idea of the design of every letter in the alphabet.

Comment: You always have the option of analyzing the image - I'm guessing that's a complete project in and of itself :-P